# How to modify node js response

Tags: node.js, ntlm

I'm using node js as a proxy for rest services which use NTLM authentication.
I use `httpntlm` module to bypass NTLM authentication. This module makes additional request and returns a response.

How can I write NTLM response data to original response?

```
var httpntlm = require('httpntlm');
var request = require('request');

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    httpntlm.post({
        url: url,
        username: username,
        password: password,
        workstation: '',
        domain: domain,
        json: req.body
    }, function (err, ntlmRes) {

        // console.log(ntlmRes.statusCode);
        // console.log(ntlmRes.body);

        res.body = ntlmRes.body;
        res.status = ntlmRes.statusCode;

        next();
        // req.pipe(res);
    });
});
```

Comment: Replace next and res object changes with this `res.status(ntlmRes.statusCode).send(ntmlRes.body)`

Comment: @RistoNovik than you very much! It works! Could you please post your comment as the answer? - and I will mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example code you provided the Express.js middleware is used but calling simply `next()` hand overs to next middleware and does not output anything. Instead of that we have to send the response back to client.

```
var httpntlm = require('httpntlm');

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    httpntlm.post({
        url: url,
        username: username,
        password: password,
        workstation: '',
        domain: domain,
        json: req.body
    }, function (err, ntlmRes) {

        // Also handle the error call
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).send("Problem with request call" + err.message);
        }

        res.status(ntlmRes.statusCode) // Status code first
           .send(ntmlRes.body);        // Body data
    });
});
```